# Detect keyboard layout pressing a serie of keys

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop on which I managed to install Lubuntu, but the system didn't detect the right keyboard layout. I know how to change it, but I don't know its name, so I'm stuck.

Is there a way to identify it with a wizard like the one Ubuntu uses during its installation that asks the user to press a series of keys? To be clearer, I'm looking for the tool you can use clicking on the `Detect Keyboard Layout` button at this step (or a similar one):

[image: Ubuntu installation - Keyboard layout]

Comment: Lubuntu has a GUI for scrolling and searching available keyboard layouts, hasn't it? Somewhere in keyboard settings I'd guess.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I know where the list is, the problem is that I don't know what is my keboard's layout, so I can't pick the right one from the list if not by trial and error - and there are some hundreds items

Comment: But you must have _some_ idea of which language etc. the layout is supposed to support, and with that narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

The screen mentioned above is part of the package `ubiquity`. You can install it if not available with the following:

```
sudo apt install ubiquity
```

And then for me, it worked to start ubiquity in a terminal. Then on the second screen, the keyboard selection occurred. I've started the detection: figured out it was a French keyboard (AZERTY) :). Then abort in the installation window and adjusted the right keyboard in the usual settings.